# Ansible parsing json

Tags: json, ansible

I am using an Ansible module (vmware_guest_info) with this code:

```
- name: Get status of VM post-change
  vmware_guest_info:
    datacenter: "xxxx"
    hostname: "{{ result_item.vcenter }}"
    username: "{{ xxxx }}"
    password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
    name: "{{ result_item.vmname }}"
    schema: "vsphere"
    validate_certs: no
    properties: ["config.hardware.memoryMB", "config.hardware.numCPU", "config.hardware.numCoresPerSocket"]
  register: postvmname_vminfo
  loop: "{{ result.list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: result_item
```

It produces the following JSON:

```
   {
    "results": [
      {
        "ansible_loop_var": "result_item",
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "instance": {
          "config": {
            "hardware": {
              "memoryMB": 4096,
              "numCPU": 6,
              "numCoresPerSocket": 1
            }
          }
        },
```

The command that produces the json is looping though an excel file with these contents:
vmname    vcenter
Server1   Vcenter1
Server2   Vcenter1

I need to create a dictionary between vmname and numCPU.  How can I do this?

I have tried this:

```
- set_fact:
    resultCPU: "{{ instance.config.hardware.numCPU }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ postvmname_vminfo.results | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: "[?invocation.module_args.name=='{{ result_item.vmname }}']"
  loop: "{{ result.list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: result_item
```

I get item is undefined from the above.  I believe the issue is with my query.   I think what I really need to do is use zip to create a dictionary between the servers(vmname) in my Excel file and the value of numCPU.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: at least put a valid `json`

Comment: Hi Julia L welcome to SO. You will want to include your attempt thus far, along with any error message you are receiving. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section. Good luck

Comment: Which ansible module are you using that produces this json?